# deploying a xrc inside other xrc

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm implementing my user interfaces with wxFormBuilder using the external XRC methodology.

I'm trying to implement an array of panels that is hanging from a wxStaticBoxSizer in this way:

```
MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) {

    wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame((wxFrame*)this,  (wxWindow*)NULL , wxT("MyFrame1"));

    wxStaticBoxSizer* almacenador = (wxStaticBoxSizer*)FindItem(XRCID("Contenedor"));

    if (!almacenador){
        cout << "Error cargando sizer!" << endl << flush;
    }

    wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadPanel( (wxWindow*)almacenador , wxT("MyPanel6"));
    wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadPanel( (wxWindow*)almacenador , wxT("MyPanel6"));
    wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadPanel( (wxWindow*)almacenador , wxT("MyPanel6"));

    SetTitle(title);
    SetIcon(wxICON(appicon));
    SetSize(size);
    SetPosition(pos);

    Show(true);
}
```

Where resources were loaded from "main" function with its

```
wxXmlResource::Get()->Load("rc/resource2.xrc");
```

lines. When launch my programs it works, by I can't see the three panels anywhere.

This is my XRC's files:

The main Frame:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<resource xmlns="http://www.wxwindows.org/wxxrc" version="2.3.0.1">
    <object class="wxFrame" name="MyFrame1">
        <style>wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL</style>
        <size>283,401</size>
        <title></title>
        <centered>1</centered>
        <aui_managed>0</aui_managed>
        <object class="wxPanel" name="m_panel1">
            <style>wxTAB_TRAVERSAL</style>
            <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                <object class="sizeritem">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                    <border>5</border>
                    <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                        <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALL|wxALIGN_BOTTOM</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxStaticText" name="m_label_Nombre1">
                                <label>Nombre</label>
                                <wrap>-1</wrap>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <flag>wxEXPAND|wxTOP|wxRIGHT|wxLEFT</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxTextCtrl" name="m_text_Nombre">
                                <value></value>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
                <object class="sizeritem">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <flag>wxALIGN_TOP|wxEXPAND</flag>
                    <border>5</border>
                    <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                        <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALL|wxALIGN_BOTTOM</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxStaticText" name="m_label_Apellidos">
                                <label>Apellidos</label>
                                <wrap>-1</wrap>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <flag>wxTOP|wxRIGHT|wxLEFT</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxTextCtrl" name="m_text_Apellidos">
                                <value></value>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
                <object class="sizeritem">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                    <border>5</border>
                    <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                        <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALL|wxALIGN_BOTTOM</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxStaticText" name="m_label_Edad">
                                <label>Edad</label>
                                <wrap>-1</wrap>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALIGN_BOTTOM|wxALIGN_RIGHT|wxTOP|wxRIGHT|wxLEFT</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxSpinCtrl" name="m_spin_Edad">
                                <style>wxSP_ARROW_KEYS</style>
                                <value>0</value>
                                <min>0</min>
                                <max>10</max>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
                <object class="sizeritem">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <flag>wxEXPAND | wxALL</flag>
                    <border>5</border>
                    <object class="wxStaticLine" name="m_staticline1">
                        <style>wxLI_HORIZONTAL</style>
                    </object>
                </object>
                <object class="sizeritem">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                    <border>5</border>
                    <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                        <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <flag>wxALL|wxEXPAND</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxRadioBox" name="m_radioBox_Sexo">
                                <label>Sexo</label>
                                <selection>0</selection>
                                <content>
                                    <item>Hombre</item>
                                    <item>Mujer</item>
                                </content>
                                <dimension>1</dimension>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <flag>wxEXPAND|wxALL</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxStaticBoxSizer">
                                <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                                <label>Preferencias</label>
                                <object class="sizeritem">
                                    <option>0</option>
                                    <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                    <border>5</border>
                                    <object class="wxCheckBox" name="m_checkBox_Cocacola">
                                        <label>Cocacola</label>
                                        <checked>0</checked>
                                    </object>
                                </object>
                                <object class="sizeritem">
                                    <option>0</option>
                                    <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                    <border>5</border>
                                    <object class="wxCheckBox" name="m_checkBox_FantaNaranja">
                                        <label>Fanta naranja</label>
                                        <checked>0</checked>
                                    </object>
                                </object>
                                <object class="sizeritem">
                                    <option>0</option>
                                    <flag>wxALL</flag>
                                    <border>5</border>
                                    <object class="wxCheckBox" name="m_checkBox_FantaLimon">
                                        <label>Fanta Limon</label>
                                        <checked>0</checked>
                                    </object>
                                </object>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
                <object class="sizeritem">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <flag>wxEXPAND</flag>
                    <border>5</border>
                    <object class="wxStaticBoxSizer" name="Contenedor">
                        <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
                        <label>Contenedor</label>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALL</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxButton" name="m_button4">
                                <label>MyButton</label>
                                <default>0</default>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
                <object class="sizeritem">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <flag>wxALIGN_BOTTOM</flag>
                    <border>5</border>
                    <object class="wxBoxSizer">
                        <orient>wxHORIZONTAL</orient>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALL</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxButton" name="m_button_Guardar">
                                <label>Guardar</label>
                                <default>0</default>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALL</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxButton" name="m_button_Limpiar">
                                <label>Limpiar</label>
                                <default>0</default>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                        <object class="sizeritem">
                            <option>0</option>
                            <flag>wxALL</flag>
                            <border>5</border>
                            <object class="wxButton" name="m_button_Salir">
                                <label>Salir</label>
                                <default>0</default>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object>
                </object>
            </object>
        </object>
    </object>
</resource>
```

And the second one (The object to be repeated as array):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<resource xmlns="http://www.wxwindows.org/wxxrc" version="2.3.0.1">
    <object class="wxPanel" name="MyPanel6">
        <style>wxTAB_TRAVERSAL</style>
        <size>500,300</size>
        <object class="wxBoxSizer">
            <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
            <object class="sizeritem">
                <option>0</option>
                <flag>wxALL</flag>
                <border>5</border>
                <object class="wxButton" name="m_button5">
                    <label>FRAME2</label>
                    <default>0</default>
                </object>
            </object>
        </object>
    </object>
</resource>
```

How to make an array of XRC panels inside the main XRC?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your program should die horribly because you are casting from `wxStaticBoxSizer` to `wxWindow`. I really wonder what could have given you the impression that it would be a good idea to do this.

Second, there is no provision for repeating objects in XRC and, generally speaking, if you need something like this, it's easier and better to create 3 different panels in the code, loading each of them from the same resource. But you could also use [`object_ref`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_xrcformat.html#overview_xrcformat_object_ref) XRC tag to reference an existing object from some other place if you really want to.

Comment: Ok, you are right... casting from wxWindows to wxStaticBoxSizer type shouldn't work (but seems to work ??? aggg :S). So how do I get the sizer pointer if I can't do it with FindItem?

Comment: I will try doing it as you said. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need the sizer pointer at all? It's rarely necessary. If you do need it, the simplest is to get either the window using the sizer and use its `GetSizer()` or a window contained in this sizer and use its `GetContainingSizer()`.

Comment: Creating 3 panel in code and loading the same XRC panel on them, works ok. Thanks.